# What is the name of the idea that humans are granted rights?

Tags: ethics, rights, human-rights

Some say that human beings are granted rights, and this becomes the basis for a claims in parts of the Western legal system. Other parts of the Western legal system consider these *privileges* that are specific grants from an authority - but have an equivalent legal remedy.

My question is: **What is the name of the idea that humans are granted rights?** (and that these are not considered privileges)

Comment: Are you looking for "natural rights"—the idea that humans naturally, intrinsically have rights? The passive voice you're using in "are granted" is making the question more difficult to answer, because it suggests the question, "by whom?"

Comment: Great - could you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural law -  a system of right or justice held to be common to all humans and derived from nature rather than from the rules of society, or positive law. At certain point it was considered the most right law because if we got this by nature than this is in God too. Others think that we lived freely by natural laws before we became chained by society laws and positive law.

Here you can read more on the topic:
[link 1](http://www.iep.utm.edu/natlaw/)
[link 2](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/406283/natural-law)
[link 3](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-law-ethics/)
[link 4](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-law-theories/)
[link 5](http://www.rsrevision.com/Alevel/ethics/natural_law/)
Also there are alot of resources on the internet just google : natural law/natural rights

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'll have that in mind thank you for the advice

Comment: Please [edit] your answer then.

Comment: @Keelan done a bit of a lazy but if the asker is interested he can read the liks I gave :)

Comment: ok - legal positivism vs natural law. Got it.